# Eiffel Iterable implementation on MAP?

Tags: iterator, iterable, eiffel

I have a  class called MAP :

```
 class MAP [KEY,VAL]
       inherit ITERABLE [KEY]
```

I implemented the new cursor inside the map cursor which returns and

```
MAP_ITERATOR_CURSOR [KEY]
```

and passes that iterable cursor an array of KEYS to iterate through

I implemented the `MAP_ITERATOR_CURSOR [KEY]` class

```
 class MAP_ITERATOR_CURSOR [KEY]
       inherit ITERATION_CURSOR [KEY]
```

for this class I implemented the feature item: `VAL` but because the class was defined with `KEY` it won't recognize `VAL` how do I get `MAP_ITERATOR_CURSOR [KEY]` item feature to return the `VAL` associated with the key that we are on at the moment ?

Knowing that `MAP` has a function called item which take key and returns `VAL` associated with that key

```
item (k: KEY): VAL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as `MAP [KEY, VAL]` inherits `ITERABLE [KEY]`, the generic parameter of `ITERATION_CURSOR` is bound to `KEY`. However `{ITERATION_CURSOR}.item` is just a normal feature, that is subject to redeclaration, renaming, etc. Therefore several approaches can fit your need:

1. Declare `MAP_ITERATOR_CURSOR` to have two formal generics and declare `{MAP}.new_cursor` as follows:

   ```
   class MAP [KEY, VAL] inherit ITERABLE [KEY] feature
       new_cursor: MAP_ITERATOR_CURSOR [KEY, VAL]
           do
               create Result.make (Current)
           end
   end

   class MAP_ITERATOR_CURSOR [KEY, VAL] inherit ITERATION_CURSOR [KEY]
   create make
   feature
       make (t: like target)
           do
               target := t
           end
       target: MAP [KEY, VAL]
       item: KEY ...
       value: VAL
           do
               Result := target.item (item)
           end
   end
   ```

   Then the client code can look as

   ```
   across map as c loop
       -- Use `c.item` of type KEY.
       -- Use `c.value` of type VAL.
   end
   ```
2. If it is required that `{MAP_ITERATOR_CURSOR}.item` is of type `VAL`, the first way is to use exactly the same code as above but rename feature `item` that comes from `ITERABLE`:

   ```
   class MAP_ITERATOR_CURSOR [KEY, VAL] inherit
       ITERATION_CURSOR [KEY] rename item as key end
   ...
       key: KEY ...
       item: VAL
           do
               Result := target.item (key)
           end
   end
   ```

   Then the client code can look as

   ```
   across map as c loop
       -- Use `c.item` of type VAL.
       -- Use `c.key` of type KEY.
   end
   ```
3. The iteration can be performed over items of type `VAL` from the very beginning. In that case the actual generic of `ITERABLE` should be  `VAL`:

   ```
   class MAP [KEY, VAL] inherit ITERABLE [VAL] feature
       new_cursor: MAP_ITERATOR_CURSOR [KEY, VAL]
           do
               create Result.make (Current)
           end
   end

   class MAP_ITERATOR_CURSOR [KEY, VAL] inherit ITERATION_CURSOR [VAL]
   create make
   feature
       make (t: like target)
           do
               target := t
           end
       target: MAP [KEY, VAL]
       item: VAL
           do
               Result := target.item (key)
           end
       key: KEY
               -- This feature can be not exported, or even not present
               -- as soon as `item` can be implemented.
   end
   ```

   The client code is similar to case 2, but `key` may be unavailable:

   ```
   across map as c loop
       -- Use `c.item` of type VAL.
   end
   ```
4. In 3 the formal generic `KEY` in `MAP_ITERATION_CURSOR` is kept for convenience. It can be removed provided that there is some way to access items of `MAP`, but this may raise some other issues related to access to `MAP`, conformance and CAT-calls. Therefore though it's potentially feasible, I would not go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using TABLE_ITERABLE [G,K] ?

cf https://svn.eiffel.com/eiffelstudio/trunk/Src/library/base/elks/kernel/table_iterable.e

Comment: sorry but that didn't work for the purpose that I want it thanks is there is a way to keep my original design and still return the value when the user uses across map as it loop it.item to return the value of the map ?