# eiffel across an_iterable as vs is

Tags: loops, iterator, iteration, eiffel

I didn't find the documentation about the difference between `is` and `as`

I'd like to implement an iterator something similar to [this MAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437491/eiffel-iterable-implementation-on-map), I'd like to know what TYPE is returned with the `is` keyword and with the `as` one.

- I think the **is** will be the `item` of the `ITERATION_CURSOR [G]` class
- Does the **as** return an `ITERATION_CURSOR [G]` which would be `like {ITERABLE}.new_cursor` of `ITERABLE[G]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version with `is` is a shortcut when the only feature called on the loop cursor is `item`. The shortcut removes the need to call the query explicitly. So, the following two versions are semantically equivalent:

```
across foo as x loop ... x.item ... end
across foo is x loop ... x ... end
```

In other words, the second version could be seen as automatically translated into

```
across foo as _x loop ... _x.item ... end
```

where `_x` is inaccessible and `x` stands for `_x.item`.

The type of `x` in the first version is `ITERATION_CURSOR [G]`. In the second version, it is the type of `{ITERATION_CURSOR [G]}.item`, i.e. `G`.

In fact, [the type of the cursor is derived](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24446098/333007) from the type of query `new_cursor` called on the object on which the iteration is performed. However, any additional features available in this cursor type are accessible only when using the complete iteration form of a loop with `as` and are inaccessible when using the shortcut form with `is`.

Comment: many thx, but the effective `TYPE` is the type returned by the `new_cursor` feature when inheriting from `ITERABLE` isnt it?

Comment: @Pipo Yes, I've added a paragraph that mentions it.